# How to redirect from Non sxa website to SXA website page?

Tags: sxa

I want to redirect to a page that is under SXA website. The website should be visited like `http://website1.dev/NewSxaPage`.
We have four non SXA websites and recently developed a new page in SXA.

Let us consider 4 websites as (Website1, Website2, Website3, Website4) . All of them here are non-SXA websites.

Developed a new website (SxaWebsite1). I have achieved redirection as below. I have just added below settings under  `/Site Grouping/SxaWebsite1/` in SXA website.

[image]

SXA websites are not resolving correctly so used Sitecore.XA.SitesToResolveAfterSxa.config as defined in the belo url.
https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/sxa/17/sitecore-experience-accelerator/en/manage-multiple-sites-with-the-sxa-site-manager.html

I'm able to achieve whatever needed. i'm able to visit the SXA page from non SXA website. it returns 200 status code.

Is it correct approach? Do you suggest any better approach?

I have just tried a new scenario like if we add any additional SXA websites in future, it's not redirecting.